# Missing edit histories on old questions?

Tags: discussion, edits, revision-history

I just came across the question [Difference between singleton methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605973/difference-between-singleton-methods/12606021) from 2012.

As the answers and the "Edit:" note in the question clearly show, the question has been edited to fix a typo after the answers were posted. However, no edit history is shown to me.

In another case I noticed the question [C++ Pass A String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475634/c-pass-a-string/43407019) from 2010 has several, also highly up-voted, answers, most of which seem to ignore that there is nothing wrong with the code in the question. It also doesn't show any edit history, but now I am wondering whether the original question was different.

Is there some issue with edit histories of old questions? How should such cases be handled? Not only are the answers not matching the questions anymore, but it is also not possible to retrieve the original context.

Comment: The first question's edit was made within the 5-minute grace period.

Comment: To add to @SamuelLiew's comment, [back before Mar 2015](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251876/241919), questions that were edited while in grace period (5 minutes after posting) wouldn't leave new revision history even if answers/comments had been posted on the question.

Comment: The second question kind of makes me sad, so many upvotes for junky answers. But that's what you get for a question that has lived for more than 10 years I guess. The fact that several answers and comments reference the fact that there is nothing wrong with the code in the question is proof that it was not changed though.